Type '{ [x: string]: any; items: Items; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'
I'm trying to map over an array and and an object, but for some reason I'm getting a TypeScript error Type '{ [x: string]: any; items: Items; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
What am I doing wrong? The [x: string]: any; is throwing me off in the error since I didn't specify that in my type Items.
Any help would be appreciated
type Items = Record<string, string[]>;

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Items>({
    A: ["1", "2", "3"],
    B: ["4", "5", "6"],
    C: ["7"],
  });
  const [containers, setContainers] = useState(Object.keys(items));

  return <div>
    {containers.map((containerId) => (
        {items[containerId].map((itemId) => (
          <p>{itemId}</p>
        ))}
      ))}
  </div>;
}


Please include all relevant code as plaintext in the question itself. Links to code are not sufficient to be a [mre]. Until the code is included here as plaintext, the question risks being closed as needing debugging details.

sorry, fixed it.

So is this just a typo? Why do you have items[containerId].map(⋯) wrapped in curly braces? You have plenty of errors in there, not just the one you're mentioning. One of them is ": expected". If I get rid of those curly braces like this then the errors go away. If this is just a typo, how should we proceed here? An answer that says "check all your error messages and fix syntax errors first"?

sorry, I tried fixing it as much as I could but I couldn't figure out what was causing the error

type Items = Record<string, string[]>;

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Items>({
    A: ["1", "2", "3"],
    B: ["4", "5", "6"],
    C: ["7"],
  });
  const [containers, setContainers] = useState(Object.keys(items));

  return <div>
    {containers.map((containerId) => (
        items[containerId].map((itemId) => (
          <p>{itemId}</p>
        ))
      ))}
  </div>;
}

Needed to remove the curly brackets around the items[containerId].map((itemId)
